# Sailsjs beforeCreate not adding new value to values object

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am trying to set a value to the values object, but sails ignores it.

```
attributes: {

    title: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    testAttr: {
        type: 'integer'
    }
}


beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {

   values.testAttr = 1;

   cb();
},
```

My values object does NOT contain a testAttr value when it enters the beforeCreate method as this value is not sent via the request.

It could seem like it wont add/update this unless it is present on the values object to begin with.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What version of Sails are you using?

Comment: We use version 0.12.11

Comment: Hm, I'm not able to reproduce this on Sails v0.12.11.  I tried with both sails-disk and sails-postgresql adapters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it almost right. The callback `cb` expects two arguments: an error, and a values hash. You just need to pass on your values:

```
beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {
    values.testAttr = 1;
    cb(null, values);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but actually it does not according to the docs [link](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks). I also tried what you suggested and it did not work. I have also tried printing the entire values object after I set the testAttr attribute and it is not there - it is ignored completely.